# StartActivityForResult not firing OnActivityResult

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am writing an Android program in C# using Xamarin that will scan a barcode (by calling the Barcode Scanner app) and then check the code against a web service.

I can't get the result back from the Barcode Scanner though. That app seems to be starting and ending correctly but the OnActivityResult method isn't firing.

Here's my code:

```
namespace AndroidApplication1
{
[Activity(Label = "AndroidApplication1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        //Start Barcode Scanner program
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        //intent.PutExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
        StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    public void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
    }
}
}
```

I have tried various things such as making the'O' in OnActivityResult lower case and uncommenting the intent.PutExtra etc

Does anyone know what is wrong?

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method, so that it's overriding the base `Activity` class:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
}
```

The `Activity` class you're extending most likely contains a virtual method like this:

```
protected virtual void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
}
```

You're currently hiding the underlying virtual method, and your method will never get "hit" as-is.

Comment: I a real novice at Android, so could you be more specific please? If I replace my OnActivityResult method with that one or add it, it says there is no suitable method to override. Sorry if this response seemed curt initially; I hit Return before I finished it.

Comment: Got it, thanks! It was also the second result code need to be of type Result, so: protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)